# I cannot hover the dropdown

Tags: html, css, hover, less, dropdown

Sometimes when I hover the button, the dropdown not work, but sometimes it jiggling (moving up and down) like crazy.

I made this with LESS only and this is my dropdown HTML Button

```
<b>Hello, <a href="{{$session->role=='admin'?'/back_office':'#'}}">{{$session->name}}</a></b>
    <span class="dropdown-title">
      <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="/history">Payment Ticket History</a>
        <a href="/ticket">Payment Ticket</a>
      </div>
    </span>
```

And this is the code in LESS file:

```
.dropdown-title {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  .dropbtn {
    &:hover {
      display: block;
    }
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 2em;
    z-index: 1;
    a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #ced6e0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did I write the codes wrong? Let me know in your comment section.

Comment: You should also fix your HTML. In the first line, you got the opening and closing tags mixed up (`<b><a></b></a>`), and `div` can not be a descendant of `span`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting. I already fix that on my code

Comment: You also forgot to add `}` to the end of the less code.

Comment: I already add } on my project. I just copied it not carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set `display:block` for `.dropdown-content` not for `.dropbtn`

```
.dropdown-title {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  &:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }

  .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 2em;
    z-index: 1;
    a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #ced6e0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit: The hover works while hovering but I cannot click on dropdown menu. It suddenly disappear

Comment: I added full code, please make sure it looks like your code

Comment: It finally works before you edit and gave me your entire code. Thanks for your help